# Assign Keydown event to all textBoxes

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to assign a keyDown event to all textBoxes in one form.

So far my code:

```
        void listenTextBox_KeyDownEvent(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
                tb.KeyDown += new EventHandler(textBox_KeyDown);
            }
            else
            {
                listenTextBox_KeyDownEvent(ctrl);
            }
        }
    }
    void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("Great Enter was hit");
        }

    }
```

But I am running in an error which I don't understand:

> No overload for 'textBox_KeyDown' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Any advice?

Comment: Okay found my mistake had to change EventHandler to KeyEventHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
tb.KeyDown += new EventHandler(textBox_KeyDown);
```

for

```
tb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox_KeyDown);
```

Comment: Thats what I commented ;) But thanks to makes thinks clear for future visitors. so +1